# What should my database be for Ionic?

Tags: database, ionic-framework

I'm new with Ionic and I was wondering what should I use as my Database. I tried to research and it seems that they were using SQLite as the database. Any other options?

Intended use:

I will store a small number of user data like the name, password, and email only. Also, for the large part, where I can save long text, audio, and images. What database should I use? Any advice from you guys?

Thanks!

Comment: SO is for specific programming questions, not for platform suggestions.

Comment: It is not recommended to save large files such as videos and audios in Database. There are lot of options. And it is nothing to do with ionic. Ionic is client side framework and Database must be in the server side.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Generally, surveys of "what tool should I use" are considered off-topic because they attract a lot of opinions.

Comment: what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Google Firebase. I used it for few of my projects. They have real-time database, file storage...
https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: Thanks for suggesting! I have no idea why they won't just suggest something.